# Block Swing pop-up from losing focus and closing

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I'm developing a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA, which obviously uses Swing.
For a feature I have introduced I'd like to stop a `JPopupMenu` which uses `JCheckBoxMenuItem`s from losing focus and closing.
You can see it in action.

[image]

I've debugged the code, but I couldn't figure out how to do it, also being I'm not *that* into Swing.
Could you maybe point me to useful listeners/blocks of code/ways to prevent this?

If you want to see code, the IntelliJ classes are

```
ActionPopupMenuImpl.MyMenu
ActionMenuItem
```

Comment: Check out: [Keeping Menus Open](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/09/12/keeping-menus-open/). You might be able to use those classes.

Comment: @camickr thanks! I'll let you know. Need to experiment.

Comment: @camickr being that I can't subclass the IDEA classes (or better, I can't change which class gets instantiated), and thus can't override doClick, maybe I can intercept the click event by listening to events on the ButtonModel (setPressed/setArmed). What do you think?

Comment: I don't let the IDE dictate what I can or can't do. The IDE should only be used to help you debug code and so on. It should not be used to generate your code. If you write your own code you are in full control. I didn't write the code so I don't know what the work around might be.

Comment: @camickr I meant that I can't subclass or chance the IntelliJ IDEA core code, so I can only work through listening to events

Comment: @camickr done! Thanks for the ideas ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: <s>a better way need to be found as the `uiRefreshed` event isn't always called at the right time.</s>
Just coordinate **your** code in a good way ;)

---

The Swing mechanism in IDEA is too complicated, and maybe it's better to not touch it. Just know that the mouse events are handled by a special listener and then redirected to Component(s).

That said, having an hold on the menu `ActionButton`. You can listen for the `Lookup`'s `uiRefreshed` event and programmatically:

```
myMenuButton.click()
```

That's all.
You need to call it after the UI has been refreshed because the `LookupUi` might have changed in dimension or location.

[image]